# Unable to send Headers and jwt token to ASP.NET signalr using client react-native-signalr

Tags: asp.net, react-native, signalr

We're using ASP.NET as backend and react-native as client for our mobile application. We've implemented signalr in back-end for push notifications. Now it's time for us to subscribe those notifications in front-end. 
I've used npm react-native-signalr for subscribing to push notifications via signalr implemented in ASP.NET.

So, the issue is when I'm removing authorization from ASP.NET and just simply subscribing without passing headers it works. But after applying authorization I'm unable to figure out how to pass headers.

Even after doing R&D I managed to pass the headers but it then also gives error while negotiating with the host.

```
const headers = {
      // organizationId: 'AD663F6D-2BD6-C538-AA56-ED3F4E9E915E',
      // userId: '9981d6a9-33be-309b-c2ca-c1bed3797da4',
      // tokenId: '',
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // projectId: '3f3bfed1-aa59-40a5-83c7-720707742df6',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
    }

    // const connection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl, { headers: headers });
    const connection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl, { headers: headers });
```

Comment: @Pradeep thanks for editing I know there were few spelling and new line mistakes

Comment: Hello! How you manage the authentication on the server side? Also please provide your startup code.

Comment: I'm a front-end developer, I don't have the back-end code. I'm just provided with request parameters to pass in headers